# Error in authentication when subscribing to a sharepoint webservice using ksoap2-android

Tags: android, authentication, sharepoint-2010, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am writing an Android application that will use the getlist() method of the lists.amx service in sharepoint 2010. I am using ksoap2-android to handle my soap messages.  When I try to authenticate I get an xmlpullparser exception expected START_TAG...
Why will the following code not authenticate to the sharepoint server?

Here is my code:

```
public class SharepointList extends Activity {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetList";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" ;
private static final String URL = "http://<ip of sharepoint server>/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

private TextView result;
private Button btnSubmit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
            {
                String list = getMobileTestList();
                result.setText(list);
            }

        }

    });


}
private String getMobileTestList()
{
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("listName");
    pi.setValue("Mobile Test List");

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization","Basic " +authentication));
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try
    {
        transport.debug = true;
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers);
        //transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        return result.toString();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the transport.requestdump (preceeding '<' removed):

- v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  - v:Header />
  - v:Body>

    - GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" id="o0" c:root="1">

      - listName i:type="d:string">Mobile Test List
  - /GetList>
  - /v:Body>
- /v:Envelope>

Here is the transport.responsedump (preceeding '<' removed):

- !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

  - HTML>
  - HEAD>

    - TITLE>Bad Request
    - META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  - /HEAD>
  - BODY>

    - h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
    - hr> p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
  - /BODY>
- /HTML>

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try the following:

```
String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

By default the Android Base64 util adds a newline character to the end of the encoded string. This invalidates the HTTP headers and causes the "Bad request".

The `Base64.NO_WRAP` flag prevents this and keeps the headers in tact.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the "Bad request".  However, I am now receiving a xmlpullparserexception "unexpected type (position:TEXT 403 FORBIDDEN...."  I know the username/password are correct because I can enter the site with them on the emulators browser.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You're completely right! Changing this line avoid my 400 "Bad request" response error!